# Repeat script through multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a script that converts the HTML value from an element into a percentage, the percentage value then determines the width of another element (in this case a bar).

This is all well and good for a single element (as you will see), however, does not work when I have an element echoing through a page. Can I be pointed in the right direction here?

Current JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctalke/27no66rm/

```js
//==================================== Bar Percentage Start ================================//
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('term')[0].innerHTML;
var b = document.getElementsByClassName('age')[0].innerHTML;
var c = 100;
var d = b / a;
var e = d * c;

document.getElementsByClassName('barv')[0].style.width = Math.round(e) + '%';
document.getElementsByClassName('barv')[0].innerHTML = Math.round(e) + '%';
//==================================== Bar Percentage End =================================//

//===================================== Bar Colour Start ==================================//
var a1 = document.getElementById("barv");

if (e < 50) {
  a1.className += " green";
} else if (e < 99) {
  a1.className += " yellow";
} else {
  a1.className += " red";
}
//===================================== Bar Colour End ==================================//
```

```css
.bar {
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black!important;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!-- Term -->
<div class="term hide">36</div>
<!-- Age -->
<div class="age hide">35</div>
<!-- Progress Bar -->
<div class="bar barv red"></div>

<br>

<!-- Term 1 -->
<div class="term hide">36</div>
<!-- Age 1 -->
<div class="age hide">2</div>
<!-- Progress Bar 1 -->
<div class="bar barv yellow"></div>

<br>

<!-- Term 2 -->
<div class="term hide">36</div>
<!-- Age 2 -->
<div class="age hide">15</div>
<!-- Progress Bar 2 -->
<div class="bar barv green"></div>
```

Comment: By 'echoing through a page', do you mean multiple elements that should get converted?

Comment: We need your code that is not working in order to fix it.  For example if you are using this line as in the fiddle, it will not work for multiple elements.  var b = document.getElementsByClassName('age')[0]

Comment: Where are `term` and `age` coming from? Do they need to be in hidden `div` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate over the snippet using a for loop instead.

```
var bars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');

for (i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
    // Your code here
}
```

And replace `[0]`  with `[i]`

```js
//==================================== Bar Percentage Start ================================//
var bars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');

for (i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('term')[i].innerHTML;
  var b = document.getElementsByClassName('age')[i].innerHTML;
  var c = 100;
  var d = b / a;
  var e = d * c;

  document.getElementsByClassName('barv')[i].style.width = Math.round(e) + '%';
  document.getElementsByClassName('barv')[i].innerHTML = Math.round(e) + '%';
  //==================================== Bar Percentage End =================================//

  //===================================== Bar Colour Start ==================================//
  var a1 = document.getElementsByClassName("barv")[i];

  if (e < 50) {
    a1.className += " green";
  } else if (e < 99) {
    a1.className += " yellow";
  } else {
    a1.className += " red";
  }
}
//===================================== Bar Colour End ==================================//
```

```css
.bar {
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black!important;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!-- Term -->
<div class="term hide">36</div>
<!-- Age -->
<div class="age hide">35</div>
<!-- Progress Bar -->
<div class="bar barv red"></div>

<br>

<!-- Term 1 -->
<div class="term hide">36</div>
<!-- Age 1 -->
<div class="age hide">2</div>
<!-- Progress Bar 1 -->
<div class="bar barv yellow"></div>

<br>

<!-- Term 2 -->
<div class="term hide">36</div>
<!-- Age 2 -->
<div class="age hide">15</div>
<!-- Progress Bar 2 -->
<div class="bar barv green"></div>
```

You can reduce the repetition of same selectors by caching them in a variable instead.

```
//==================================== Bar Percentage Start ================================//
var bars = document.querySelectorAll('.bar');

for (i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
  var bar = bars[i];
  var term = document.querySelectorAll('.term')[i];
  var age = document.querySelectorAll('.age')[i];
  var a = term.innerHTML;
  var b = age.innerHTML;
  var c = 100;
  var d = b / a;
  var e = d * c;

  bar.style.width = Math.round(e) + '%';
  bar.innerHTML = Math.round(e) + '%';
  //==================================== Bar Percentage End =================================//

  //===================================== Bar Colour Start ==================================//
  if (e < 50) {
    bar.classList.add("green");
  } else if (e < 99) {
    bar.classList.add("yellow");
  } else {
  bar.classList.add("red");
  }
}
//===================================== Bar Colour End ==================================//
```

Comment: This was a great explanation how I could fix my issue!

Thank you for providing that extra tip at the end there!

Answer (score 0):

I might be misreading your question, but are you asking about looping through all of the elements? If you're trying to do something to more than 1 element, try something like this

```
const arrayOfElements1 = document.querySelectorAll('yourCSSselectorGoesHere');
const arrayOfElements2 = document.querySelectorAll('yourCSSselectorGoesHere');
for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfElements.length; i += 1) {
    arrayOfElements1[i].doStuff;
}
```

In the `doStuff` above you can do `arrayOfElements1[i].innerHTML / arrayOfElements2[i].innerHTML * 100`. I'm not entirely clear on what you're needing so let me know if I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code in a for loop.

```
var barvs = document.getElementsByClassName("barv");
for (var index=0; index<barvs.length ;index++) {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('term')[index].innerHTML;
  var b = document.getElementsByClassName('age')[index].innerHTML;
  var c = 100;
  var d = b / a;
  var e = d * c;

  barvs[index].style.width = Math.round(e) + '%';
  barvs[index].innerHTML = Math.round(e) + '%';

  var a1 = barvs[index];
  if (e < 50) {
    a1.className += " green";
  } else if (e < 99) {
    a1.className += " yellow";
  } else {
    a1.className += " red";
  }
}
```